# @RequestParam annotation in Spring MVC with YearMonth value

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get a query param of the following format "2018-01" to be used as a YearMonth (java.time) object.

In my controller, I have the following param:

```
@RequestParam(value = "start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM") YearMonth start
```

but I get the following error:
*Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.YearMonth]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.YearMonth]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found*

Edit:
According to this link: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13518 , the java.time.YearMonth conversion is supported since version 4.2.4, and I'm using spring version 4.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: can you use `LocalDate` instead of YearMonth? (I haven't used `@DateTimeFormat`, just a thought)

Comment: look at the end of the error message: `no matching editors or conversion strategy found`. It means Spring cannot find either a property editor or a converter to converter your `String` to a `YearMonth` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if YearMonth is supported by the @DateTimeFormatter annotation for implicit conversion. But

you can always registered custom Converter for this YearMonth type like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMvc 
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new YearMonthConverter());
    }
}
```

with your YearMonthConverter defined as:

```
public class YearMonthConverter implements Converter<String, YearMonth> {

    @Override
    public YearMonth convert(String text) {
        return YearMonth.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM"));
    }
}
```

there you are assured of implicit conversion.

Comment: I would have liked to use the Spring annotation because according to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13518 it is supported since version 4.2.4. Anyway, I tried your solution and it works.

Comment: you should edit your answer to add the Configuration annotation on the WebMvcConfig class, in case someone else might need to use your answer